# c++ setting only pointer of object to nullptr

Tags: c++, pointers, stack

Let's say I have an array `a` which holds pointers to objects of a class `B`. Let's say `a[0]` points to object `c`.
If I now set `a[0] = nullptr`, will the `destructor` of `c` be called and thus `c` destroyed if `c` was constructed on the stack and if `a[0]` was the only thing referencing `c`.

Comment: Are those **smart** pointers?

Comment: Depends on the scope (and a lot of other things too). Please add some actual code, not a description of it.

Comment: @ StoryTeller no, regular pointers pointing to stack allocated objects

Comment: `B` is a class so what `B[0]` means?

Comment: All you're doing is a simple assignment. There's no destruction of objects (but perhaps a *leak*). It's basically the same as `int a; a = 5; a = 0;` If the object `c` is on the stack, then it will be destructed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: @ CIsForCookies B was supposed to be a. Fixed it

Comment: @StefanB - Regular pointers. If you understand the difference between them and smart pointers, you should know the answer.

Comment: Bigger question: If `c` was constructed on the stack (and hasn't already been destroyed), how can a pointer in an array possibly be the only thing referencing it?

Comment: please create a [MCVE]. Don't describe the code. Post actual code.

Comment: If `c` is on the stack as you say in the comments. How can `a[0]` be the only thing referencing `c`? You mean except from the variable `c` that is defined in the same scope? The question will make more sense if you could present how `c` was defined/allocated.

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to regular pointers (Obj* ptr) so c's d'tor would not be called **because of the assignment**. It might be called if there's a code like -

```
... // Some code and initialization before
{
Obj c;
a[0] = &c;
a[0] = NULL; //c isn't affected in any way by this assignment
} //End of scope. **c's d'tor is called here**
```

Although, if c was allocated on the heap, it's memory would have leaked